# Overriding classes with class_alias

Tags: php, overriding, customization

I know this is a really bad idea, but I ran out of ideas, so I'd like to hear some opinions about it.

I'm working on a PHP project which allows the development of addons so that other developers can add their own functions, not so different from thousands of other open-source projects:

```
root
└── addons
    └── addon-a
    └── addon-b
    └── addon-c
```

I have to implement some changes to an already made addon (let's say Addon A) without changing the original files or using [Composer PSR-4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34600074/7970301). Unfortunately, the original author did not follow good practices that would help to accomplish this task. Here's how the Addon A is:

**Structure**

```
addon-a
└── main.php
└── classes
    └── Foo.php
    └── Bar.php
```

**addon-a/main.php**

```php
include_once __DIR__ . '/classes/Foo.php';
function run() {
    echo AddonA\Classes\Foo::returnTwo();
}
```

**addon-a/classes/Foo.php**

```php
namespace AddonA\Classes

use AddonA\OtherFolder\FooBar

abstract class Foo {

    public static function returnTwo() {
        return 2;
    }

    public static function returnFooBar() {
        return new FooBar();
    }

}
```

I need to override the `returnTwo` function and return another value. Without changing other files, the only way I was able to do it was through the [class_alias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) method, copying the whole Foo class:

First, I created another addon and made it ran **before** the Addon A "run" function:

**Structure**

```
new-addon-a
└── main.php
└── classes
    └── Foo.php
```

**new-addon-a/main.php**

```php
function init() {
    include_once __DIR__ . '/classes/Foo.php';
    class_alias( 'NewAddonA\Classes\Foo', 'AddonA\Classes\Foo', true );
}
init();
```

**new-addon-a/classes/Foo.php**

```php
namespace NewAddonA\Classes

use AddonA\OtherFolder\FooBar // No changes to the previous "uses."

abstract class Foo {

    public static function returnTwo() {
        return 3;
    }

    public static function returnBar() {
        return new AddonA\Classes\Bar(); // Here I had to change because the namespace has changed
    }


}
```

Now, when Addon A executes the function `run`, the `AddonA\Classes\Foo::returnTwo` will be my own class.

---

Well, as I said before, this is pretty ugly, and I would lose any update to the Foo code since I'm overriding the entire class. However, this was the only way I thought. Do you think it would be possible to use another method?

Thanks!