# Laravel overide PutenvAdapter vendor class

Tags: php, composer-php, overriding, autoload, vendor

I want to override get, set and clear function of \Dotenv\Environment\Adapter\PutenvAdapter.
I've tried to copy and edit this file to \App\PutenvAdapterCustom.php and use ServiceProvider but it does not use this file but the vendor file.

Try 1 (AppServiceProvider)

```
 $this->app->singleton(\Dotenv\Environment\Adapter\PutenvAdapter::class, function () {
      return new \App\PutenvAdapterPatch;
  });
```

Try 2 (AppServiceProvider)

```
$this->app->bind('Dotenv\Environment\Adapter\PutenvAdapter', 'App\PutenvAdapterPatch');
```

Try 3

```
//Config/app.php providers add => App\Providers\PutenvServiceProvider::class,
//AppServiceProvider
    public $singletons = [
        Dotenv\Environment\Adapter\PutenvAdapter::class => PutenvServiceProvider::class,
    ];
//PutenvServiceProvider
    //Same code in Try 1 & 2
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Hi, emeliku, you can use app() instead of $this->app. And, did you set aliases to the singletons in config/app.php ?

Comment: @bluepine using app() does not change anything. What alias, I tried several things like this but it didn't work: 'PutenvAdapter' => App\PutenvAdapterPatch::class and 'Dotenv\Environment\Adapter\PutenvAdapter' => App\PutenvAdapterPatch::class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strategy to override a class in a library installed with Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104574/strategy-to-override-a-class-in-a-library-installed-with-composer)

Comment: Your question has more to do about autoloading and composer than about laravel itself.

Comment: @N69S IDK, i dont want override all vendor lib (vlucas/phpdotenv) but only 1 file so I can't replace "Dotenv\\": "src/"

Comment: @emeliku that is exactly what the answer is providing. You put only the file you want to override.

Comment: @N69S I dont know how to do that because PutenvAdapterPatch (the file I've created) is not called in the project, and PutenvAdapter (the vendor class I've override) is only use in Dotenv vendor. So how to tell laravel that instead of using the Dotenv\Environment\Adapter\PutenvAdapter file it should use the App\PutenvAdapterPatch file.

Comment: Read the answer and edit your composer.json then run `composer dump-autoload`. it's not laravel that is handling the classes in the vendor folder (or even app folder) it's the composer autoload follwing the https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/